# lyx - Lost table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, preamble

All has been going well for weeks, but in an attempt to change font-style in headers, I've lost the table of contents: e.g. it doesn't show up in the pdf.

**** Here's my preamble:

```
% DO NOT ALTER THIS PREAMBLE!!!
%
% This preamble is designed to ensure that the User's Guide prints
% out as advertised. If you mess with this preamble,
% parts of the User's Guide may not print out as expected.  If you
% have problems LaTeXing this file, please contact 
% the documentation team
% email: lyx-docs@lists.lyx.org

\usepackage{ifpdf} % part of the hyperref bundle
\ifpdf % if pdflatex is used

 % set fonts for nicer pdf view
 \IfFileExists{lmodern.sty}{\usepackage{lmodern}}{}

\fi % end if pdflatex is used

% for correct jump positions whe clicking on a link to a float
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}

% the pages of the TOC is numbered roman
% and a pdf-bookmark for the TOC is added
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \frontmatter
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \mainmatter }

% define a short command for \textvisiblespace
\newcommand{\spce}{\textvisiblespace}

% macro for italic page numbers in the index
\newcommand{\IndexDef}[1]{\textit{#1}}

% for customized page headers/footers
% only needed because they are only used in one section of the document
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% change header rule width
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
% workaround for a makeindex bug,
% see sec. "Index Entry Order"
% only uncomment this when you are using makindex
%\let\OrgIndex\index 
%\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{\OrgIndex{#1}}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily\upshape}
```

**** And here's the lyx code:

```
dedicated to:Laurie, love of my life--- LloydJackie, my best half--- Jesseand to:the Open Source giantswho have given usLinux, Erlang, Nitrogen and so much else--- LRP & JG

\maketitle
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter*{Authors' Note}
```

**** Oh where o where can I find it again?

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: Note that unnumbered chapters (`\chapter*{}`) does not show up in the ToC, so if your author's note is the only sectional unit in your document the ToC will be empty, only the ToC heading will show up. Is this the case, or has the ToC heading disappeared as well? If not, can you create a *complete* example and add this to your post instead of the two snippets? To do that, create the smallest document you can in LyX that demonstrates the problem, export it to LaTeX code, and edit your question to include all of that code, from `\documenclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: So when you say "...here's the LyX code", is that what you type in the LyX window?

Comment: Thanks for responses. The problem seems to a memory leak or hardware. When rebooted, the toc came back. Should I put this in answers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem disappeared after rebooting.